# Post data on Web using C++ Script

Tags: c++, scripting, automated-tests, testcomplete

I am using TestComplete 7. In this for configuration I have to post XML on web at specified IP and port address. I am using  C++ Scripting language. How can I do this? or if there is other way to do same using interface and without scripting??

Comment: @Tony: It's a proprietary language used in the automated testing tool TestComplete. Basically, it's JScript/JavaScript with square bracket notation.

Comment: @Tony: yes. As TestComplete gives you facility that you can write your routines in the form of C++ script. After that you can use those Script in your test cases.

Comment: @Ali: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "post XML on web"? Upload an XML file to a web site? Pass an XML file to a web service? Something else?

Comment: @Helen: I want to post XML like the following;  "<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Config>
<Video_Input_Source>IP CAM 3</Video_Input_Source>
</Config>"   to an IP address and port. Actually we have IP cameras on networks. I am writing automated test cases for their testing. But before testing we have to configure IPcameras for testing. we can configure them by posting XML.

Comment: How do you manually upload the files to these cameras? Via FTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need something like this:

```
  XmlHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
  XmlHttpRequest.open("POST", "http://camera.ip/configuration_page", false);
  XmlHttpRequest.send("<?xml version="1.0" ?> <Config> <Video_Input_Source>IP CAM 3</Video_Input_Source> </Config>");
```

This is JScript. This code will work in a C++Script TC project.
But there may be problems with the "new ActiveXObject" statement in a C++ application if you put the code there. So, you will need to modify the code to use a different way to create the same "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0" object in your C++ app. The idea remains the same.